# In C, trying to remove extra whiteSpace in char* and replace with only one space between words

Tags: c, compression, whitespace, c-strings, removing-whitespace

I am trying to remove unnecessary whitespace from my char* for future use. Basically, I want to only have one space between words and remove any additional spaces, tabs, or new line characters in between words. The current code I have almost works I believe, but I am unable to read the memory of the individual characters I am storing in my array. Also any solution must not have a maximum character size so if dynamic memory allocation is needed that would need to be considered as well. Is there a way to get this working? Thanks

EDIT 1: trailing and leading spaces should also be removed. Thanks to @Vlad from Moscow for the clarification

```
int main()
{
    char* fileString1;
    fileString1=removeAdditionalWhiteSpace(fileString1);
}
char* removeAdditionalWhiteSpace(char* wordList) 
{
    char characterHolder;
    char* finalList[strlen(wordList)];
    char* delimeter = wordList;
    int i = 0;
    do 
    {
        finalList[i] += characterHolder;
        char* hasSpace = NULL;
        while (*delimeter == ' ' || *delimeter == '\n' || *delimeter == '\t')
        {
            if(*delimeter == ' ')
            {
                if(hasSpace==NULL)
                {
                    hasSpace = delimeter;
                    characterHolder = *delimeter;                           
                }
                else
                {
                    ++delimeter;
                }
            }
            else if(*delimeter == '\n' || *delimeter == '\t')
            {
                *delimeter = ' ';
                if(hasSpace==NULL)
                {
                    hasSpace = delimeter; 
                    characterHolder = *delimeter;                          
                }
                else
                {
                    ++delimeter;
                }
            }
        }
        hasSpace=NULL;
        characterHolder = *delimeter; 
        i++;      
    } 
    while( (*wordList++ = *delimeter++) );
    return *finalList;
}
```

Comment: "I believe". Please be more precise. What exactly is the problem? Does it crash? Does it work with some input and not others? Also, is that really your code? `fileString1` is not set to anything. Please give an example of exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: `finalList[i] += characterHolder;` In the first loop `characterHolder` has not been set to anything.

Comment: `finalList[i]` also hasn't been initialized.

Comment: I don't understand what this code is doing at all. `finalList` is an array of pointers, but you never allocated any memory for the pointers to reference.

Comment: Why are you adding a character to a pointer?

Comment: You don't need an array of pointers, just a single string: `char *finalString = malloc(strlen(wordList) + 1)`

Comment: @DegaClaw It is unclear whether you need to remove leading and trailing spaces of a string

Comment: Why do you use a second buffer? Stuff like this can be done in-place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does not make sense and has undefined behavior.

For example the variable `characterHolder` was not initialized and it is added to pointer `finalList[i]`

```
char characterHolder;                 // <===
char* finalList[strlen(wordList)];
char* delimeter = wordList;
int i = 0;
do 
{
    finalList[i] += characterHolder;  // <===
    //….
```

If you need to remove redundant white spaces from a string including its leading and trailing white spaces then the function can look as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * remove_duplicate_spaces( char *s )
{
    char *src = s, *dsn = s;

    while ( isspace( ( unsigned char )*src ) ) ++src;

    do
    {
        char c = *src;

        if ( isspace( ( unsigned char )c ) ) c = ' ';

        if ( c == ' ' )
        {
            while ( isspace( ( unsigned char ) *++src ) );
            if ( *src )
            {
                *dsn++ = c;
            }
        }

        *dsn++ = *src;
    } while ( *src++ );

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "\t\tIt is\t\ta      very\nlong\nstring.\t\t";

    printf( "\"%s\"\n", s );

    printf( "\"%s\"\n", remove_duplicate_spaces( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
"       It is       a      very
long
string.     "
"It is a very long string."
```

Answer (score 0):

Man that looks super complicated.

Here's a simple function to remove whitespace from the string:
`"  This   is a test  \t of some   \n Extra white  space.  "`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void removeWS(char* text)
{
    char* d = text;

    while (isspace(*text)) ++text;

    while(*text)
    {
        *d = isspace(*text)? ' ' : *text;
        text++;
        while (isspace(*d) && isspace(*text)) ++text;
        if (*text) d++;
    }

    *d = *text;
}


int main(void) {
    char text[] = "  This   is a test  \t of some   \n Extra white  space.  ";

    removeWS(text);
    printf("%s\n", text);

    return 0;
}
```

### Sample Output:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4284KB
This is a test of some Extra white space.
```

Comment: Simple, but O(n^2). Would be faster and about equally simple if you copied into a buffer rather than trying to operate in-place. Of course it doesn't matter for one line like this, but for a big file...

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Not O n^2. The two loops bump the same pointer.

Comment: He needs spaces only between the words. You should trim the string as well

Answer (score 0):

Minimalistic approach:

---

```
size_t delspaces(char * str)
{
size_t src, dst;
size_t cnt;

for (cnt=src=dst=0; str[dst] = str[src++]; ) {
        if (isspace(str[dst])) {
                if (dst && !cnt++) str[dst++] = ' '
                continue;
                }
        cnt=0;
        dst++;
        }

        // remove trailing spaces
while (dst && isspace(str[dst-1])) str[--dst] = 0;

        // return the string length of the resulting string
        // (which could be useful for the caller)
return dst;
}
```

---

Final note: the last `while()` could be an `if()`, since there can be only one trailig space.